# What is ETA short for?

Tags: scala, terminology, lambda-calculus

I've only found some indirect clue from [eta expansion](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#method-values)

> SimpleExpr    ::=  SimpleExpr1 
>   `_' The expression  _ is well-formed if  is of method type or if  is a call-by-name parameter. 
>   If  is a method with parameters,  _ represents  converted to a function
>   type by eta expansion. 
>   If  is a parameterless method or call-by-name parameter of type =>,  _ represents the function of type () => , which evaluates  when it is applied to the empty parameterlist ().

So i guess eta is short for expression to anonymous function? Am i right?

Comment: Yes, more precisely to a subclass of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eta is the greek letter η and in this case stands for extensionality. It comes from the lambda calculus. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#%CE%B7-conversion

Comment: I see. <br/>α-conversion: changing bound variables (alpha);
β-reduction: applying functions to their arguments (beta);
η-conversion: which captures a notion of extensionality (eta).

Comment: β-reduction is more about substituting the argument of a function into its body, you reduce an application. We talk about α-renaming and η-expansion (or η-contraction when going the opposite direction).